# Should we use the [red-flags] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

While I do appreciate the addition of the new [red-flags](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-flags) tag as it provides me a convenient list of questions to vote to close as opinion-based, I think it's probably in the best interest of the site to not have this as a tag.

Do we need this tag, and what do we believe it is for?

Comment: Stop voting to close just because a question has a tag and vtc the question based on it's own merits

Comment: I am, it just makes it easy to find the bad ones.

Comment: Seems that the consensus is to remove this tag. I went ahead and did so, as I also strongly thing that way as well.

Comment: @Kilisi apparently you aren't familiar with how [meta-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-tags/info) work. These describe tangential question properties instead of content, could also happen to indicate if it's close-worthy. That's why vast majority SE sites try to avoid such tags

Comment: @gnat correct, I have no idea

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, [red-flags](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-flags) is not a valid or helpful tag and should not be used.

1. It's a meta tag, per https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/. It is entirely unsatisfactory as a single tag on a question. It's like having a tag of [problem] or [things-I-dont-like]. It may as well be on almost every single question on the site describing something someone finds negative about a company, employee, candidate, HR department, etc. What does it mean to be an expert in the [red-flags] tag?  Nothing.  Why would you search on it (other than to find things to fight about, or find opinion-based questions to close?) No reason.  It covers bullying bosses and slow recruiters and employees with strange habits - it's a valueless meta tag. Also its meaning is not clear, which I'll cover next.
2. Its definition is not uniform across its users. What does it mean to say something's a "red flag?"  Something that's negative at all?  Something that's so negative you shouldn't work there/employ that person/etc? Rather than encouraging people to use their words as to what their actual concern is, it encourages people to use a poorly defined/scoped term of "red flag" and move on as if they'd actually communicated.
3. And this is closely related to the third and fatal problem - using the term "red flag" is a very accurate marker for opinion based questions on the site. "What are issues to look out for in a candidate that spent 15 years in their previous job" is a good question.  "Is it a red flag that a candidate spent 15 years in a previous job" is a crap question.  It's looking for a yes or no answer, and that yes or no answer is a purely individual opinion/value judgement. People may add useful information to their answer, but through no benefit of the question - or of the [red-flags] tag associated with it.

I propose @Lillienthal stop adding this tag to questions and burninate it instead.

Comment: Seems that the consensus is to remove the tag. I am of that same opinion. I proceeded and removed the tags from the only 3 posts that had it.

Comment: For the record: I added it to a handful of questions after it was created for a popular question and wasn't planning to add it to others. Re point 2 I think the main use of the tag would be for question where the actual question is "Should I consider this a red flag?" meaning there's no need for a fixed definition on the tag itself. I personally don't consider to be any more of a meta tag than [tag:professionalism] and arguably more useful. But it seems there's clear consensus against using it so that's fine with me. We probably overtag as it is. :)

Answer (score 9):

While I don't think this will **always** translate as meaning the underlying question will be opinion-based I do think it's a bad tag.

Primarily because it's a horribly over-used, too-broad buzzphrase - people throw it around as though it actually means something but can never explain just *what* it means or if they can it never seems to agree with what other definitions people have given. Which, effectively makes it mean *nothing* and making it into a tag does nothing to resolve that issue, and just makes it worse.